# VS2012 c++ <Error reading characters of string.>

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, runtime-error

I'm trying to debug a c++ project in visual studio 2012 and when attempting to view a string value I get the error 'Error reading characters of string.'. 
The only relevant article I can find is here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/721456

but my project has none of the relevant preprocessor options set.

Heres a screenshot to show exactly what I mean

[error http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1682/09112012100524.png](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1682/09112012100524.png)

Any help on this error would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a release or debug build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xcdcdcdcd` Is a special marker sequence used in Microsoft debug builds and shows the presence of uninitialized memory:

[Well known magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)

This rather suggests that you haven't initialized the string inside your `AptConstItem`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and it was a problem in my build definitions.  I could debug some variables but not others.  I had to turn off all optimizations.  In C/C++ -> Optimization and Linker -> Optimization.